# How can I stop Minecraft Pocket Edition from automatically loading the world when I open the app?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why does it auto load the world when I start MC:PE? Please help me fix it.

It's on Android, the version is v0.14.0.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with Pocket Edition is that it does not auto-load the world.  Some versions of Android, however, do not close the app when you go back to your home screen.  In this case, when you "start" the app, it resumes where you left off.  To completely close the app, while in the app, tap the back keypad. This (if you are in a world) gives you the option to go to the main menu, and once there, tapping the back keypad again exits the app.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the same behavior as in Windows Phone. Not sure about iPhone, though.